# ERROR new to chef

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra, databags

New to Chef, bare wi/ me.  Building my cookbook.

Comment: How are you testing this? With Test Kitchen?

Comment: Wi/ Vagrant.  Created a test VM wi/ Vagrant & added the recipe to it's run list.

Answer (score 0):

How did you set the databag?

are you able to get the credential out using :

```
$ knife vault show nameOfVault nameOfItem
```

or

```
$ knife data bag show nameOfVault nameOfItem_keys
```

Comment: I didn't use knife to create the databag, but rather just create a new 'data_bags' directory & created the JSON file inside the directory since I'm using Vagrant to run it.  Is that wrong what I did?  Or can I still use knife to see if I can get the credentials?

Comment: chef need to recognize the databag ,can you see the databag in chef manage?

Comment: I'm not using the Chef Manager as I'm only running it on a Vagrant VM.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you have your data bag loading and indeed, with Test Kitchen you do not need to use knife to upload to Chef Server, as Test Kitchen uses Chef Zero / Solo.

The issue you have here is that you have not correctly formatted reading from the data bag object once you have read. You need to do this instead:

```
ruby_block "insert_line" do
  block do
    file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new('/var/lib/net-snmp/snmpd.conf')
    file.insert_line_if_no_match("/www.example.com/", "createUser 
       #{snmp3usercreds['user']} 
       SHA #{snmp3usercreds['auth_pssword']} 
       AES #{snmp3usercreds['enc_password']} ")
    file.write_file
  end
end
```

So, you will see I have changed `snmp3usercreds[user]` to `snmp3usercreds['user']` with quotes around the `user` to show it is a string (rather than a variable as is the case with your code).

Comment: Thank you.  Can't believe I missed that.  However, I think I may have spoken too soon on the data bag correctly loading.  When I use snmp3usercreds = data_bag('snmp3_user_creds'), it loads, but I don't think this is correct as I should be using:  snmp3usercreds = data_bag('snmp3_user_creds', 'credentials').  When I do that, it's still not loading.  Any ideas?

Comment: I meant to say I should be using data_bag_item('snmp3_user_creds', 'credentials').